# Prove $\Sigma_{k\geq0} \frac{x^k}{x^k+1}$ converges uniformly when $|x|\leq r$ for $0<r<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove $\Sigma_{k\geq0} \frac{x^k}{x^k+1}$ converges uniformly when $|x|\leq r$ for $0<r<1$.

I want to use Weierstrass M-test to prove the statement. However, I cannot find a $M_k$ such that $M_k\geq \left|\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}\right|$.

Comment: $|\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}|\lt|x^k|\le r^k=M_k$, for $|x|\le r\lt 1$.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis Thanks for your comments. But $|x^k+1|$ can be smaller than $1$ since $x$ could also be negative.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can use $|\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}|\lt |x^{k+1}|\le r^{k+1}=M_k$, for negative $x$, with $-1\lt-r\lt x\lt 0$. It's the absolute value that matters on using the M-test (minus was a typo on previous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|x^k+1|\geq 1-|x^k|$, so $|\frac{x^k}{x^k+1}|\leq \frac{|x^k|}{1-|x^k|} \leq |x^k| \leq r^k$, the uniform convergence can be concluded by the convergence of $\sum_{k\geq 0} r^k$